# Apache Storm: How many topologies can create in a cluster?

Tags: java, apache-storm

I read many sites related to Storm's topologies design setup. But, I didn't get clarity.

In my project, I am going to processing more than a million records. So, I planned to create topologies dynamically based on internal modules. The count might be reached more than a thousand. My doubt is what is the best way to manage topologies? How many topologies can be created in a single cluster? Are there any problems with maintaining multiple topologies?

Answer (score 1):

I would say, that this really depends on your machines in the cluster, so it is hard to answer that generally - this is especially true, if the cluster has heterogeneous instances.

Basically storm can handle many topologies that you can control over the [CLI](http://storm.apache.org/releases/current/Command-line-client.html) or the GUI.

I am currently managing those with `storm list` and `storm kill` commands. Limits should be in the RAM, storage and network connections of the single machines. To be precisely, I would predict, that the bottleneck is the **JVM size of a supervisor instance**. This can hold multiple workers (that each having components like bolts & spouts that are initially configured with a JVM of 256 MB), but if there are too many workers, the overall consumed JVM per supervisor will be exceeded.